# Add missing values to grouped data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

This is a follow up to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61603807/format-grouped-data-from-json-data). I get my grouped value by date from the array of objects. When I group the values can I fill in the metric as 0 when grouped by date for missing types per day.

This is my array:

```
arr = [
        {
           "date": "2020-01-01",
           "metric": 32,
           "type": "Google"
        },
        {
           "date": "2020-01-01",
           "metric": 24,
           "type": "Bing"
        },
        {
           "date": "2020-01-02",
           "metric": 1,
           "type": "Google"
        },
        {
           "date": "2020-01-02",
           "metric": 32,
           "type": "Jeeves"
        },
        {
           "date": "2020-01-03",
           "metric": 24,
           "type": "Bing"
        },
        {
           "date": "2020-01-03",
           "metric": 30,
           "type": "Google"
        }
    ]
```

This is how I group the data:

```
const groupBy = (array, key) => {
    return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
      (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(currentValue);
      return result;
    }, {});
};

const personGroupedByColor = groupBy(arr, 'date');
```

My result is:

```
2020-01-01: 
0: {date: "2020-01-01", metric: 32, type: "Google"}
1: {date: "2020-01-01", metric: 24, type: "Bing"}
2020-01-02: 
0: {date: "2020-01-02", metric: 1, type: "Google"}
1: {date: "2020-01-02", metric: 32, type: "Jeeves"}
2020-01-03: 
0: {date: "2020-01-03", metric: 24, type: "Bing"}
1: {date: "2020-01-03", metric: 30, type: "Google"}
```

Is there any way I can get:

```
2020-01-01: 
0: {date: "2020-01-01", metric: 32, type: "Google"}
1: {date: "2020-01-01", metric: 24, type: "Bing"}
2: {date: "2020-01-01", metric: 0, type: "Jeeves"}
2020-01-02: 
0: {date: "2020-01-02", metric: 1, type: "Google"}
1: {date: "2020-01-02", metric: 0, type: "Bing"}
2: {date: "2020-01-02", metric: 32, type: "Jeeves"}
2020-01-03: 
0: {date: "2020-01-03", metric: 30, type: "Google"}
1: {date: "2020-01-03", metric: 24, type: "Bing"}
2: {date: "2020-01-03", metric: 0, type: "Jeeves"}
```

Can I replace the missing values with the metric of **0**?

Comment: Why do you want the `metric` 0? i think the output is already correct.

Comment: it does not accurately chart  when I create a stacked column chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Set` of all the different `type` values, then iterate over each value in `personGroupedByColor`, checking to see that they have all of the different `type` values, and if not, pushing a new object with that type and a metric of `0`:

```js
arr = [{
    "date": "2020-01-01",
    "metric": 32,
    "type": "Google"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-01-01",
    "metric": 24,
    "type": "Bing"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-01-02",
    "metric": 1,
    "type": "Google"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-01-02",
    "metric": 32,
    "type": "Jeeves"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-01-03",
    "metric": 24,
    "type": "Bing"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-01-03",
    "metric": 30,
    "type": "Google"
  }
]

const groupBy = (array, key) => {
  return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
    (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(currentValue);
    return result;
  }, {});
};

let personGroupedByColor = groupBy(arr, 'date');

const types = new Set(arr.map(a => a.type));

for (a in personGroupedByColor) {
  types.forEach(t => {
    if (!personGroupedByColor[a].some(v => v.type == t)) {
      personGroupedByColor[a].push({
        "date": personGroupedByColor[a][0].date,
        "metric": 0,
        "type": t
      });
    }
  })
}
console.log(personGroupedByColor);
```